# How to Give Credit for Background Images

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm using a background image (creative commons attribution license) on one of my pages. There was no direction on *how* to attribute the image. I want to give credit to the source, but since this is a (css) background image, I can't use a `title` or `alt` and I can't give the image a `caption`, so I'm wondering what the best way is. Some things I've thought of are

- Add a comment in the css file
- Add a comment in the HTML file
- Add a 'credits' section in the footer.
- Add the info in a humans.txt file

I've seen [THIS QUESTION](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/how-should-creative-commons-attribution-for-images-be-shown), but the "how" remained largely undetermined. Is there a standardized way to do this?

Comment: Just a thought - how about adding/ensuring the EXIF data (ie metadata) of the image contains the appropriate credits?

Comment: @davidgo I suppose I could open the image in Photoshop to see/add EXIF data, but still, that seems like a rather occult way to give credit, the info is not easily accessible to the average user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar situation, I  decide to have an attributions page, where I listed each author, linked to their website, and explained what I used. I  also thank them at the top.

I am giving them credit for their work so that any visitors can see the attribution.   I  have seen many sites use this scheme.

I use **nofollow** links.   But you can choose to exclude that attribute.

Comment: I was wondering about that approach. Naturally, I don't want the attributions page to come up in search results. But MDN [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel ] says that rel=nofollow "Indicates that the current document's original author or publisher does not endorse the referenced document." That is kind of the opposite of what I want to accomplish, so I'm confused.

Comment: Endorsement is your choice.  I don't think its warranted unless the author requests it or you have an arrangement with them.

Comment: Well your response is reasonable, so I think I will follow your advice and mark this as answered. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how widespread it is, but some sites use a humans.txt file to give credit to the people behind the site. Like robots.txt, it should be put at the root of the site.

The [humans.txt site](https://humanstxt.org/Standard.html) gives a number of additional recommendations. For example, you can put `<link rel="author" href="humans.txt" />` in your `<head>` to make it more discoverable.

Here's an [example humans.txt](https://jacek-nowacki.net/humans.txt) that credits CC works.